# Rescript Capitalised Component

Tags: reason, rescript

From the **Rescript** [Documentation](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/jsx#fragment), it is suggested spread can be used to enable passing a pre-existing list to a component. I am confused what exactly `MyComponent`is in Rescript as I cannot find a way to initialise a component, which can be done with a function in vanilla React.

```
<MyComponent>...myChild</MyComponent>
```

where `myChild = list{child1,child2}`

After several attempts, the followings **do not** work:

- `@JSX div(~children=myChild)` , because Rescript asks for wrapping it in a list as in `list{myChild}`
- `@JSX div(~children=list{myChild})`, which gives a type error
- Initialising a module named MyComponent, and do `<MyComponent> ...myChild </MyComponent>`, but this gives the error `The value make can't be found in MyComponent`
- Initialising a function with a capitalisation escape: `let \"MyComponent" = () => ...`, but this gives the error `The module or file MyComponent can't be found.`

What I would love is an example of the initialization of the component `MyComponent` which can be used as a capitalised tag like `<MyComponent>...myChild</MyComponent>`. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module MyComponent = {
 @react.component
 let make = (~children: list<React.element>) => {
   <div> {Belt.List.toArray(children)->React.array} </div>
 }
}
```

From [Rescript Forum](https://forum.rescript-lang.org/t/capitalised-jsx-component/809/2).